# nativescript installation android virtual device issue

Tags: android, nativescript

I am very new to nativescript. While I am installing nativescript as a first time user, I followod the instruction in the official website. Quick setup does not work properly. So, I follewed the advanced setup for windows in the website. While installing Android requirements for nativescript. I stuck with @powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://www.nativescript.org/setup/win'))" command.

Then I decided to install every dependency one by one. I followed the http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/start/ns-setup-win instructions. Then in step 6, I cannot find the sdk Manager. Because of that, I download the sdk using the android studio. After that I cannot find the virtual device manager without using android studio.  So, my emulator setup does not complete. I am stuck here and I don't know what I have to do?

Thanx.

Sorry for bad English.

Comment: Open Android Studio; 

Tools -> Android -> AVD

Comment: Thanx @pkanev ..

Answer (score 0):

You can open your command prompt and type in `android`. Then the SDK manager will launch without Android Studio. There you can open your AVD by click on `tools` then `AVD Manager`.